# Dynamic change of custom attribute in configurable product. M2.3

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.3.1, dynamic

I need to change custom attribute and sku every time when customer change color and size 
(http://prntscr.com/nwzt1h).
With sku i found [article](https://magecomp.com/blog/switch-product-sku-according-selection-child-products-magento-2/) how to do it and it's working, but i can't find some info how to do the same with **custom** attribute. I found place where i need to enter info to dynamicly change it (location of this files `Vendor\Extension\Plugin\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable\Configurable.php` and `Vendor\Extension\Plugin\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable.php` [here](http://prntscr.com/nwzwv2) and [here](http://prntscr.com/nwzx6b) . But "getData" "getCustomAttribute" "getAttributeText" "getAttribute" doesn't work. I found out if i will write `$simpleProduct->getData('size')` i will see dynamic changes [example1](http://prntscr.com/nx00st) [example2](http://prntscr.com/nx013q) . But with my **custom** attribute it doesn't work this way. Can anyone give me some advise, or link on article where this problem solving ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the same issue, you need to add `$jsonResult['some_identifier'][$simpleProduct->getId()] = $simpleProduct->getResource()->getAttribute('your_custom_attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($simpleProduct);`

So it will look like this: 1) http://prntscr.com/nx39w5
2) http://prntscr.com/nx3ark

And in admin panel your custom attribute must be "Global" and have this settings http://prntscr.com/nx3boh